# Formatting a MicroSD card within OSX

Tags: macos, format, osx-mavericks, intel

I am trying to format a 32GB MicroSD card using the Disk Utilities app in OSX

[image]

however I am receiving this error:
[image]

I need that for processing with [this manual](https://software.intel.com/en-us/programming-blank-sd-card-with-yocto-linux-image-os-x).

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general hardware tech support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly write this command in the terminal:

```
diskutil list
```

Then it will show a list of disks. Find the one which caused the problem and use this command for it:

```
sudo diskutil unmountDisk /dev/disk4
```

Now it should be erased successfully if you get back to the Disk Utilities program.